# charset="8Bit" can be interpreted as us-ascii?

Tags: character-encoding, 8-bit

I am using javamail and trying to process emails that has `Content-Type: text/html; charset="8Bit"` can i assume this as us-ascii or is there a better equivalent?

Comment: Does the content have meta charset? Content-Type should override but 8Bit is not a character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

US-ASCII is the lowest common denominator of all character sets and it is a seven bit character set. `"8Bit"` is no character set! The used character encoding should be specified i.e. iso-8859-1 or utf-8.
Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Comment: Not that W3S is the most accurate reference to link to…

Comment: Okay, you are right, thx! More details in: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en or https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5 ;-)